# Set image data into input file tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, image, input

I have a string code in a javascript variable that i get from cropit plugin (plugin to crop images).
Is there any way to set this info into an input file tag to send it then by ajax to php?

This is the code i have in javascript and how i get it from the image:

```
  var imageData = $('.image-editor').cropit('export');
```

this variable is something like this: http://encargaya.com/imagefile.txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just dump that base64 string into a hidden input and POST with that.  It's unnecessary to try and put it in an input file tag.

Comment: Ok, let me try if i can solve the problem that way, Thanks for your time